# AngularJS Ui-Router nested views not working with html5mode

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using `AngularJS` with `ui-router` and I have a problem with nested views while using `Html5Mode`. This problem only happens with html5, if I'm not using it, everything works fine. I tried to work with base `<base href="/">` but didn't work as well.

Also, the problem only happens within nested views, on the main `ui-view` it's ok.

This is the code I'm using:

***index.html***

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li ui-sref="menu">Menu</li>
        <li ui-sref="user">User</li>
        <li ui-sref="contact">Contact</li>
    </ul>
    <div ui-view autoscroll="false"></div>
</div>
```

***child template.html***

```
<div class="container">
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li ui-sref="user.data">My Info</li>
            <li ui-sref="user.order">My Order</li>
            <li ui-sref="user.budget">My Budget</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div ui-view></div>
</div>
```

***app.js***

```
.state("user", {
    url: "/User",
    templateUrl: "content/user.html",
    controller: "UserCtrl"
})
.state('user.data', {
    url:"/MyData",
    templateUrl: "content/user/user_data.html",
    controller: 'UserCtrl'
})
```

If I use the html5 WITH `, i can navigate, but when i refresh the page, I get errors like this:

`Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html`

And if I use WITHOUT `<base href="/" />` then it doesn't work at all. But again, only for the child ui-view, the parent view is still working.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't got such problem until now, so my knowledge is limiting, but i've heard a few things that can help you. As [this ui.router tutorial](http://www.codemag.com/Article/1505061) says:

> HTML5 Mode
>
> The UI Router framework gives you ultimate control over the URLs
>   generated for your site by allowing you to enable HTML5 mode. When
>   enabled, this mode does not generate hash (#) locations, but uses the
>   HTML5 history API to generate clean URLs. The only caveat to this
>   approach is that you must build your application to work under each
>   generated path, rather than just at the root, which is customary in
>   most single-page applications.

I hope this helps! Cheers.

Comment: Yeah, but what I don't understand is because it works for the parent element, but when I reload on a child state, it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: In another [discussion on github](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/105) someone who had the same issue like you, got it fixed with adding a leading `/` to the child states.

Comment: I tried those things, but none of them worked for me. Maybe it's because of the re-write property on the server-side, I'll try to take a better look at it.

Comment: did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @NoobSter It's been a while, so I don't remember exactly if this is what solve the problem, but I had to add a leading `/` on my styles. For example: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">` needs to be `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css">`